# Male personal names ending in -um

Tags: greek, names, gender

A number of personal names in the works of Plautus end in *-um* in the nominative singular, which struck me as odd when I first encountered them, since nominative singular *-um* is characteristically found at the end of neuter nouns (specifically, those of the second declension). An example is  *[Stephanium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Stephanium).* In fact, all of these names seem to end more specifically in *-ium.*

I found names ending in *-ium* discussed briefly in one section of "[Some Roman Slave-names](https://theologicalstudies.org.uk/pdf/ffb/slave-names_bruce.pdf)" by F. F. Bruce. Bruce says that these are from Greek diminutives in -ιον, which were "mainly names of women". Women's names ending in *-ium* are grammatically feminine in Latin.<sup>1</sup> (I'm not sure [how names ending in -ιον behave in Greek](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9389/how-were-names-ending-in-%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD-used-in-greek).) Harm Pinkster gives the phrase "amoena Stephanium" as an example of this principle of semantic gender assignment<sup>2</sup>.

According to Anna Morpurgo Davies, although some women's names in Greek are neuter, no men's names in Greek are neuter<sup>3</sup>. Nevertheless, in the context of Latin, there does seem to be at least one example of a **male** name ending in *-ium*: *[Paegnium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Paegnium),* the name of a male slave in Plautus' *Persa,* and one of the names of the character Tyndarus in Plautus' *Captivi*<sup>4</sup>. The Lewis and Short entry for *Paegnium* says that it comes from the Greek neuter noun *[παίγνιον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpai%2Fgnion)* 'plaything, toy', which LSJ says could also be used of persons in the sense "darling, pet". Philippides suggests a comparison with the Latin term *delicium* (p. 107).

Are there any examples other than *Paegnium* of male names ending in *-um*?

#### Citations

1. Henry John Roby, *[Grammar of the Latin Language from Plautus to Suetonius, Part 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=hIlfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA106),* p. 106
2. *[Oxford Latin Syntax: Volume 1: The Simple Clause](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y05zCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA21-IA7),* p. 40
3. *[Greek Personal Names and Linguistic Continuity](https://www.thebritishacademy.ac.uk/sites/default/files/104p015.pdf),* p. 21
4. "[Tyndarus' Past: The Name Paegnium in Plautus' *Captivi*](https://www.academia.edu/9055970/Foka_A._2011_Beauty_and_the_Beast_Femininity_Animals_and_Humour_in_Middle_Comedy_Classica_et_Medievalia_Danish_Journal_of_Philology_and_History_62_51-80)", by Katerina Philippides, *Classica et Mediaevalia* 62:1 (2011).

Comment: Excellent question. Unrelated: I'm reading the *Falco* novels by Lindsey Davis, in which figure a striking number of men with names on *-ia*, such as Famia, Laeta. I have heard similar names, and I've asked a question about masculine nouns on *-a*, but wonder how realistic their abundance in Davis is. I associate them to some degree with Etruscan names, but Laeta, for instance, doesn't sound Etruscan to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pinacium, a slave-boy in Plautus *Stichus* and also in *Mostellaria*.

Answer (score 3):

Alex B.'s answer of *Pinacium* is the only other example of a male name ending in *-um* that I have been able to find (aside from "Paecnium", which just seems to be a variant form of "Paegnium", and an unclear example I discuss in the next section below), so I have accepted that post. I wanted to make a post of my own to add some further information I have found about the name *Pinacium.*

- It seems to be from the Greek common noun *[πινάκιον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpina%2Fkion),* a diminutive of *πίναξ.* It looks like *pinacium* was also used at least sometimes as a neuter common noun in Latin, since I get Google results for phrases like "pinacium ligneum".
- In *Stichus,* there seems to be a wordplay involving this name and the Latin noun *pictura* (*[Studies in the Word-Play of Plautus](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXVvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22pinacium%22),* 1907, by Charles Mendelson, p. 23; also *[The Introduction of Characters by Name in Greek and Roman Comedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ptJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=pinacium),* 1923, by David Martin Key, p. 49). This suggests that the LSJ definition "small or bad picture" is relevant to the meaning of the name (mentioned by Charles Knapp in "[References to Painting in Plautus and Terence](https://books.google.com/books?id=YK1JAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=pinacium#v=onepage&q=pinacium&f=false)", *Classical Philology* p. 152).
- In "Plautus Undoing Himself",  Sophia Papaioannou suggests that the name might allude to food, since πινάκιον could have the sense of "small plate", but I'm not convinced about this connection (*[Roman Drama and its Contexts](https://books.google.com/books?id=9aLUCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=false),* 2016).
- The authors of some sources seem to have had the impression that *Pinacium* was a female name. For example, *[Auf Geschichte und Kritik gegründete lateinische Sprachlehre](https://books.google.com/books?id=s95FAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=Pinacium#v=onepage&q=Pinacium&f=false),* by E.J.A. Seyferts (1800), lists "Pinacium" along with female *-ium* names like *Crocotium, Dorcium, Glycerium, Chrysium,* etc. and shows "haec" as the corresponding demonstrative (p. 66). I found some discussion of the possible source of this error in "[The Scene-Headings in the Early Recensions of Plautus](https://books.google.com/books?id=9M0NAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=%22Pinacium#v=onepage&q=%22Pinacium&f=false)", by H. W. Prescott: Prescott indicates that this error may come from a scribal mistake in the "Palatine" manuscripts of the text that caused *Pinacium* to be given as the name of one of a pair of sisters in *Stichus.*

### One other possible example: Tranium?

A footnote in "[De nominibus propriis, quae sunt apud Plautum et Terentium](https://books.google.com/books?id=4TdnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA21)" (*Jahresbericht des Städtischen Katholischen Gymnasiums zu Patschkau*), mentions *Tranium* as a possible third servant name ending in *-ium* (p. 21). This name seems to be from *Mostellaria.*

"[The Declension of Greek Nouns in Plautus](https://books.google.com/books?id=9M0NAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=%22Tranium%22)", by H. M. Hopkins, indicates that the form "Tranium" occurs only once, as a heteroclitic variant form of the proper name *Tranio.* It occurs in an accusative context ("eccum Tranium") so I'm not sure that it really counts as an example of what I was asking for.